# Best way to receive integer array on c socket

Tags: c, arrays, sockets, parsing

I need to receive a nested integer array on a socket, e.g.

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],...]
```

The subarrays are always 3 values long, the length of the main array varries, but is known in advance.

Searching google has given me a lot of options, from sending each integer seperatly to just casting the buffer to what I think it should be (seems kind of unsafe to me), so I am looking for a safe and fast way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The "subarrays" don't matter, in the end you're going to be transmitting 3 *n* numbers and have the receiver interpret them as *n* rows of 3 numbers each.

For any external representation, you're going to have to pick a precision, i.e. how many bits you should use for each integer. The type `int` is not well-specified, so perhaps pick 32 bits and treat each number as an `int32_t`.

As soon as an external integer representation has multiple bytes, you're going to have to worry about the order of those bytes. Traditionally network byte ordering ("big endian") is used, but many systems today observe that most hardware is little-endian so they use that. In that case you can write the entire source array into the socket in one go (assuming of course you use a TCP/IP socket), perhaps prepended by either the number of rows or the total number of integers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that bandwidth and data size isn't very critical I would propose, that (de-)serializing the array to a string is a safe and platform/architecture independent way to transfer such an array. This has the following advantages:

- No issues with different sizes of the binary representations of integers between the communicating hosts
- No issues with differing endiannesses
- More flexible if the parameters change (length of the subarrays, etc)
- It is easier to debug a text-protocol in contrast to a binary protocol

The drawback is, that more bytes have to be transmitted over the channel as minimal necessary with a good binary encoding.

If you want to go with a ready-to-use library for serializing/deserializing your array, you could take a look at one of the many JSON-libraries available.
http://www.json.org/ provides a list with several implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize it the way you want, two main possibilities:

1. encode as strings, and fix separators, etc.
2. encode with NBO, and send data to fix some parameters: first the length of your ints, then the length of the array and then the data; everything properly encoded.

In C, you can use XDR routines to encode properly your data.